# Rails y Datatables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

Hola eh tratado de implementar Datatables en Rails 5, pero resulto que era imcompatible segun lei en stackoverflow en ingles y recomendaron otra pagina.

https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/datatables

ya segui paso a paso, pero no consigo que me aparezcan las opciones de editar, y eliminar ( yo no utilizo la opcion "show" )

y ademas no encuentro la manera de darle formato con Bootstrap y tambien hacerla responsiva

Comment: Si no muestras lo que has hecho, difícilmente recibirás ayuda

Comment: @AlterLagos Hola, pues es exactamente como esta el ejemplo de la pagina, ya compare linea x linea, la unica diferencia es que yo solo muestro 2 columnas